# Unable to activate package ‘evil’. Required package ‘goto-chg-1.6’ is unavailable

Tags: emacs

When I try to open a file with emacs, I am getting following error.

```
Unable to activate package ‘evil’.
Required package ‘goto-chg-1.6’ is unavailable
```

I neither change any config of emacs nor installed any packages on system.
I am running emacs 25.1.1 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Any pointer on what would cause the issue?

Comment: A guess is that package `evil` requires package `goto-chg-1.6` and you haven't installed that package.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. But it(error) suddenly started to appear. I did not change anything in emacs config or on system. Anyway, how should I install the package? It is not in elpa, marmalade or melpa repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541322/how-to-remove-installed-elpa-package provides solutions for the general case (in my case, I had updated my Emacs). It does not explain why it changed on your side without an update, but should help others brought here by Google.